# Align matrix on left margin. align* left-aligned?

Tags: equations, align

I have the following problem:
I put the command vmatrix inside the align* area. The result is unfortunately centered, but I'd like to have the matrix be left-aligned.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\begin{vmatrix}
f(x_0=0) & = & a_0 \\
f'(0) & = & a_1 \\
f''(0) & = & 2\cdot a_2 \\
& \vdots & \\
f^{(n)}(0) & = & n! \cdot a_n 
\end{vmatrix} 
&  \Rightarrow  a_n = \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

How can I put the matrix on the left margin?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You need to (a) load `amsmath` with the option `fleqn` and (b) execute `\setlength\mathindent{0pt}` before the start of the `align*` environment.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: @Mico -- answer, please.

Answer (score 1):

To make the displayed equation start hard at the left edge of the text block, you should (a) load the amsmath package with the option `fleqn` (short for "flush left equation", I suppose) and (b) set the `\mathindent` length parameter to `0pt`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\setlength\mathindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\begin{vmatrix}
f(x_0=0) & = & a_0 \\
f'(0) & = & a_1 \\
f''(0) & = & 2\cdot a_2 \\
& \vdots & \\
f^{(n)}(0) & = & n! \cdot a_n 
\end{vmatrix} 
&  \Rightarrow  a_n = \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```